# XSLT 1.0 - Selecting specific value from node string

Tags: string, xslt, expression, matching

I have this XML structure.

```
<Organisation>
    <Employee type="gorilla">
        <Publication>
            The Hills and the Sunrise, 1-2013-05, $94,000
        </Publication>
        <Publication>
            Sunny and Rainy on the same day, 1-2013-05, $584,932
        </Publication>
    </Employee>
    <Employee type="gorilla">
        <Publication>
            The Hills and the Sunrise, 1-2013-05, $94,000
        </Publication>
        <Publication>
            Sunny and Rainy on the same day, 1-2013-05, $584,932
        </Publication>
    </Employee>
    <Employee type="pig">
        <pigpen>
        </pigpen>
    </Employee>
</Organisation>
```

I would like to know how I can select only the dollar amount at the end of every Publication where an employe type = gorilla, and add these values together to give the total publication income. I would also like to use this total to calculate the average income per gorilla employee.

How could I go about doing this? I'm having trouble finding a function to select just the dollar amounts.

If there isn't a method to do this in XSLT 1, would it be considered good coding form to add more nodes to store the dollar amounts separately?

e.g.

```
<Publication>
  <Description>The Hills and the Sunrise</Description>
  <Amount>$94,000</Amount>
</Publication>
```

Comment: *"would it be considered good coding form to add more nodes to store the dollar amounts separately"* Yes.

Comment: There *is* a method do this in XSLT 1.0 - however, if you *can* change the structure of the XML input so that each "fact" (name, date, amount) is a separate node (either an element or an attribute), you would save yourself quite a lot of work.  -- BTW, is there something special about the one employee type? Or do you need to summarize these numbers for each employee type?

Comment: @user2285167: Also consider avoiding the dollar sign and the thousands separator. Keep just plain numbers there. If you have to support different currencies then create a dedicated element that.